# Accidentally deleted windows 7 getting error NTLDR is missing

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have formatted the C: drive accidentally on my Asus net book(No CD Drive). In response NTLDR is missing error is coming.
I tried several options like rescue cd's bootable usb with several Os like xp 7 and 8.
but it is not accepting any bootable usb.

I don't want the data, I just want to reparation and fresh install windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your bootable device and then restart your machine and in starting you continuously press '**Esc**' key it open a window that ask for choose bootable device. and choose your use device.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop does not support booting from USB and does not have an internal optical drive, you can possibly install Windows 7 from a USB CDROM-drive.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry here is a solution for it. All you need to do is boot from a USB. For that you need to change your first boot device in Bios to USB [See here](http://mashupcode.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/changing-boot-device-order/). Make sure you have a Bootable image in your USB stick or USB external storage, If you dont have a bootable Image in USB [see here to create a Bootable Image in USB](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/make-bootable-image.htm). Now you can install a fresh copy of OS.